# Pandas generator as indexer

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'user': ['Bob', 'Jane', 'Alice'], 
                   'income': [40000, 50000, 42000]})
```

I have a list of filters:

```py
f = ['A', 'B', 'C']
```

and want to get all the data like:

```py
df[df.user.str.startswith(f)]
```

Of cource this doesn't work, I write the error here for search engines, maybe it will help somebody

```
    >>> TypeError: ufunc 'invert' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [match](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.match.html#pandas-series-str-match):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'user': ['Bob', 'Jane', 'Alice'],
                   'income': [40000, 50000, 42000]})

f = ['A', 'B', 'C']
res = df[df['user'].str.match(rf'{"|".join(f)}')]
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
    user  income
0    Bob   40000
2  Alice   42000
```

From the documentation on match:

> Determine if each string starts with a match of a regular expression.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I accept your answer since it is more general.

Answer (score 4):

You need to pass a tuple.

From the [Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith):

> `str.startswith(prefix[, start[, end]])`
>
> Return `True` if string starts with the `prefix`, otherwise return `False`. **`prefix` can also be a tuple of prefixes to look for.**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'user': ['Bob', 'Jane', 'Alice'], 
                   'income': [40000, 50000, 42000]})
f = ['A', 'B', 'C']
df[df.user.str.startswith(tuple(f))]
```

**Output:**

```
    user  income
0    Bob   40000
2  Alice   42000
```

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for "not accepting" your answer, I really like your solution!